# R Aggregate by two factors

Tags: r, data.table

Suppose I have a `data.table` `x`:

```
 x <- data.table(Motif = c("A","A","B","B","B","C"),
                 Strain = c(1,1,1,2,2,3),
                 IPDRatio = c(1:6))
```

How would I find the mean of the IPDRatio column by collapsing the entire `data.table` by factors `Motif` and `Strain`?

Desired output:

```
   Motif Strain IPDRatio
1:     A      1      1.5
2:     B      1        3
3:     B      2      4.5
4:     C      3        6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
x[, mean(IPDRatio), list(Motif, Strain)]
```